# Completely unable to acess admin password due to reset

Tags: windows-10, passwords, administrator

I accidentally removed Admin permissions from my main account. For whatever reason, there is a secondary "Administrator" account that I am completely unable to login to. It also says "Password must be changed to use" so I cannot access the "forgot password" prompt. My computer is essentially useless now, and about two hours of searching for similar issues yielded no luck.

My computer is windows 10.

Comment: I presume the account you are unable to access is the built-in Administrator account?  If it is not the built-in Administrator account, you should enable the built-in Administrator account, and used that to reset the password to both of the other accounts.

Comment: No, there is an extra account titled simply "Administrator" I cannot access for these reasons. Also, I need Admin perms to even enable the build in Admin, which is poor design.

Comment: You absolutely DO NOT need Administrator permissions to enabled the built-in Administrator account.  Since you have indicated the second account you attempted to use was NOT the built-in Administrator account, I flagged this as a duplicate, of a question that has an answer that explains how to enabled the built-in account. If for some reason that actually is the account you have been trying to use, you can [edit] your question, and clarify that particular point. Doing that will automatically place the question in a queue to be reopened.